# Replacing / with - in SQL Server using Select Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I replace one char from a SQL Server `Select` command without changing the value in the table itself?

Example:

```
Select Col_Name 
from TABLE
```

returns

```
**RANDOM/ANSWER**
```

How do I modify the `Select` query to get `**RANDOM-ANSWER**` instead? So the `/` is replaced by `-`. But the data in the table remains unchanged

Comment: use the [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function

Comment: Try `Select REPLACE(Col_Name, '/', '-') from TABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function should do the trick:

```
SELECT REPLACE(my_column, '/', '-')
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Col_Name, REPLACE(Col_Name, '/', '-') AS New_Column
from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace all the sepecific character/string found in the data with the new character/string.

```
DECLARE @myValue VARCHAR(50) = 'RANDOM/ANSWER';
SELECT REPLACE(@myValue, '/', '-');

-- o/p: 
-- RANDOM-ANSWER
```